# Get device latitude and longitude without using state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

in my action folder (using redux) I would like to get the device location so I can use it to query firestore, my code returns ***undefined***. I am not exactly sure where my error is coming from. any idea how I can get the device location without storing it in my state?

```
const myCoord = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
        const LatLong = {
            'lat': latitude,
            'long': longitude
        }
        return LatLong
    });
```

Comment: Do you use expo or bare project?

Comment: @DominikTargosz I use expo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get undefined because getCurrentPosition is not done right away. It's an asynchronous function. What You can do is for example create a Promise that will be fullfilled on success of getCurrentPosition and rejected on error.

Here is how I implemented this:

```
    const myCoord = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const geoSuccess = position => resolve(position);
    const geoFailure = error => reject(error);

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      geoSuccess,
      geoFailure,
      geoOptions
    );

    const geoOptions = {
      timeout: 5000,
      maximumAge: 5000,
      enableHighAccuracy: false
    };

  });
```

And then you need to call with "then" or with "async"

I recommend reading about changing callbacks into Promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Quote from this site the best describes your problem

> In an ideal world, all asynchronous functions would already return
>   promises. Unfortunately, some APIs still expect success and/or failure
>   callbacks to be passed in the old way. The most obvious example is the
>   setTimeout() function